# .htaccess rewrite rule showing 404 page not found

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but when i go to `domain.com/admin/properties/add` it should show `domain.com/admin/index.php?id=properties/add` but instead it shows 404 page not found

Comment: Where your htaccess is placed? at DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a url that contains `a` to `z` in lower case (`a-z`), `a` to `z` in uppercase (`A-Z`), `0` to `9` (`0-9`) and a dash `-` is to be rewritten, if it doesn't exist. But the url contains a forward slash `/`, so you need to include that to the mathing 
This should fix that problem and redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thats still showing page not found - my .htaccess is located in the admin directory as i have another .htaccess file in my document root doing the main website

Comment: If you change the `[L,QSA]` to `[R,QSA]` and try the page again, what is it changed to?

Comment: Sorry about that, remove the `admin/` at the start of the rewrite rule.